# Python 3: How to loop through a text file and find matching keywords?

Tags: python, database, loops

To start, I am a complete newb to coding and don’t know what I’m doing.

I am working with a database txt file and have got it imported and open. I need to now loop through the file,  find a specific keyword (number), and print this out to a new file. I have tried endlessly to understand coding to no avail. Can someone explain how to do this to me. Please explain in a dumbed down way so an idiot like me can understand.

````
 file1 = open('database.txt', 'r')
 Lines = file1.readlines()

pattern = "gene_numbers_here"

for line in Lines:
   
  
   if pattern in line:
      print(..., file = open("gene1found.txt",'w'))```
````

Comment: Do you have some code to point us in the right direction of what you are looking for?

Comment: You can try using regex

Comment: Hey, relax on the focus of being a newb, we've all been there. Unfortunately we can't help you much if we can't see the file. Can you post an example? Happy to help!

Comment: I can't share the file but; it's a genetic database composing of over a couple hundred thousand entries. I need to find my gene of interest using python 3, and then write this into a new file (excel). Does this help? I just need some guidance with how to apply the code and get it to do what I want; basically just to extract my desired gene from the database and copy all relevant results to a new file. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use readlines to load up the txt file line by line into a list of strings

```
file1 = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
Lines = file1.readlines()
```

Now for the looping:

```
for line in Lines:
   print(line)
```

Based on your problem, you are actually wanting to do a "pattern search" in a string.
For that, just use the same code from the looping example and insert a "pattern search" function to check if your pattern exists in your txt file, line by line.

```py
# declare the pattern
pattern = "this_pattern_only"

# loop through the list of strings in Lines
for line in Lines:
   
   # patter search statement
   if pattern in line:
      print("pattern exist")
   else:
      print("pattern does not exist")
```

If you want to print this to a file, just change the print code lines I made.
Check out more on the write functionalities here:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp

Based on you new info about the code, try this:

```
# file1 is database, file2 is output
file1 = open('database.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('gene1found.txt', 'w')

Lines = file1.readlines()
pattern = "gene_numbers_here"


# search and write lines with gene pattern
print("Searching database ...")

for line in Lines:  
   if pattern in line:
      file2.write(line)

print("Search complete !")


# close the file
file1.close()
file2.close()
```

This will write the gene lines with the pattern you want to your file.

Comment: Hmm. This is how you should do the search. if you wanna print the line in a file just remove the `else print ("does not exist")` statements, and change the `print ("pattern exist")` to write the line in a file when the pattern was found. Something like, if pattern is found, print the line to a new file.

Comment: Also please, next time it would be good to share a sample code (what you have tried) and  also the sample data (if possible).

Comment: Please edit the code inside your question with proper markdown.

Comment: From what I can see, it is crashing because you have the "open" code inside the loop. Meaning its opening a file again and again.

Comment: I edited the last part of my answer, see if it works for you.

Comment: If you have pattern1, 2,3, etc, I'd suggest to just put a new if-statements like `if pattern# in line: write ...` for your specific needs. There are other ways to do it (with less codes), but this direct method is more understandable.